# Why command "php artisan serve" not working

Tags: laravel, angular

I started Laravel at this path:

```
C:\Users\Mad\Work\trunk\product\backend\v1.2.1\laravel
```

but it is not working, it is not starting.

Please give me suggestions how I will do it ?

Comment: share what is not working please. Some errors, commands you try execute and so on...

Comment: What this has to do with `angular2`, `npm` and `webstorm` (why these tags are used here)?

Comment: give more info, at least show us folder structure under `laravel` folder, what errors You're getting and etc...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

try

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

source : http://allbitsnbytes.com/posts/php-artisan-serve-not-working/

Answer (score 8):

```
composer update
```

This will update and export directories and files and then run the below command :

`php artisan serve`

or you can also try this on your terminal:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

Answer (score 5):

try to execute the command : `composer update`.
It will update and export all the directorys/files that u need.
because sometimes when u clone/download a repository from github .. there are pretty much directorys/files that are not present (not exportable .. present in .gitignor).
then try : `php artisan serve`.
it works for me

Comment: Thanks Tony, this was exactly fixing the problem for me ....

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add to Jayhuan's answer above:

Laravel does the same thing behind the scenes, you can see the [code here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php) (look in `serverCommand`).

So to serve locally you would do:
`php artisan serve --host mysite.com --port 8000`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Answer (score 0):

try only this

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing some Server Requirements

See the Laravel site for requirements.
[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8)
The Laravel framework has a few system requirements.

If you are not using Homestead, you will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:

```
PHP >= 7.1.3
BCMath PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
JSON PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
```

To see a list of your extensions... From the command line:
$ php -m

I was missing BCMath and Tokenizer so I installed them with:

$ sudo apt-get install php-bcmath
$ sudo apt-get install php-tokenizer

Now you can use $ php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers were to use `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` but this still didn't work for me. (`php artisan serve` didn't work as well)

The site was not accessible.

I tried to insert the command with **SUDO** and then **it worked for me** and the application started immediately.

```
sudo php artisan serve
```

or this worked too:

```
sudo php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you also check your path which you use in the composer like C:\Users\HP>
example:if your parent folder is blog then use
C:\Users\HP> cd blog/
C:\Users\HP>blog> php artisan serve

Answer (score -1):

There could be multiple reasons for this problem one of the reasons is using old dependencies.

step 1: Check your current version of PHP and version of dependencies if they don't match proceed to next step.

step 2:  replace the older dependencies with the newer one in `composer.json` file.

```
facade/ignition to ^2.3.6
laravel/framework to ^8.0
laravel/ui to ^3.0
nunomaduro/collision to ^5.0
phpunit/phpunit to ^9.0
```

The following first-party packages have new major releases to support Laravel 8. If applicable, you should read their individual upgrade guides before upgrading

```
Passport v10.0
Socialite v5.0
Telescope v4.0
```

Try to find the appropriate dependencies for your project and make sure u add the correct version of it in the `composer.json` file.

step 3:  Now the next step is to update the composer

```
`composer update`
```

step 4: The last step is to run the artisan serve command.

`php artisan serve`

If all the dependencies are perfect then it will work. All the best.