# Why is command php artisan serve not working anymore?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel development and have been migrating my web app to laravel for the past two weeks but suddenly my local server has stopped responding.

localhost:8000 does not load any page, previously it loaded my app's home page. Now, it looks like it is in an infinite request loop or something as indicated by the circle on the top of the tab.

I've tried the following solutions but still no luck:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

as referred here [Why command "php artisan serve" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331631/why-command-php-artisan-serve-not-working)

I have also tried other ports but I cannot successfully make a request to the server on those ports either

```
php artisan serve --port=8888
```

I have also run the code below to see which ports are active and kill those ports with the command below but starting the server after that still does not respond.

```
 ps -ef | grep php
 sudo kill some number
```

I think my issue is something deeper than switching the ports up because regardless of the port, I still do not get a server response. 
However, if I whip up MAMP I do get a response from that server, if that helps.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Update: restarted my computer and left my laptop for a few hours and it works now. Very odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you had infinite request loop try another port like this:

```
php artisan serve --port: 8090
```