# Php Artisan serve command not serving Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.8

I installed a new Laravel instance, using version 5.8. Along the way, I found out that I can't serve the project using the normal Laravel `php artisan serve` command.

After some research with lots of trial and error, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331631/why-command-php-artisan-serve-not-working) on StackOverflow that helped me with this method `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` with which I followed to change `the port` to `port 9000,` and it served the project perfectly.

Now my question is how can I go about getting the artisan command to be the default command to serve and rum my Laravel 5.8 on Windows just like before? I don't know anything about configuring Laravel core commands.

Comment: What error do you get after you type in `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: The port error is a little weird because one of the features of the `5.8` version in case of a port conflict is to try a different port from `8000` up to `8009`. So, at least you have those ports full the problem must be somewhere else. Please, use the `-vvv` option and provide the error you get.

Comment: Watch your terminal output after you try to access localhost:8000. Maybe the problem is in your PHP configuration. When you use php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ it is your PHP built-in server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this command.

```
php -S  127.0.0.1:9000 -t public/
```

after running this its works fine.

and also `php artisan serve` command works fine.

hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You should open *ServeCommand.php* file (Illuminate\Console) and then change *getOptions* method

```
protected function getOptions()
{
    $host = env('SERVE_HOST', '127.0.0.1');  
    $port = env('SERVE_PORT', 8080);

    return [
        ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', $host],
        ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', $port],
    ];
}
```

when create a *SERVE_HOST* and *SERVE_POR*T in your *.env* file

```
SERVE_HOST=localhost
SERVE_PORT=9000
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/ejlocop/2e81cd3134fbc6b7858f28eb6fd4a60f)

Comment: Don't change vendor files, the changes may be overwritten by composer. Instead, inherit your own command from it, override said method and register it (if not done automatically). It will replace the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the project on port 80. If you are using Linux simply run the command from the embedded server with root user permission.

Example: sudo php -S localhost: 80 -t public /