# Laravel `php artisan serve` throws error without meaning

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When running `php artisan serve` I get the error message:

```
$ php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
sh: line 0: exec: : not found
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8001
sh: line 0: exec: : not found
```

It will repeat trying to start on other ports but without success.

My installation worked fine a couple of days ago and I did not do any manual updates. What does the error message mean?

I also tested to setup a new Laravel project with `laravel new test` and I can properly launch this. So I assume that all my tools are still correctly installed.

Comment: check ``server.php`` exist in your project folder or not?

Comment: Yes it exists and has the same content as when I create a fresh installation.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376773/6212294) answers you?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI No, unfortunately not. The path is configured as described in the linked question and the path is also sourced. Other laravel apps are working correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290052/php-artisan-serve-command-not-serving-laravel-5-8

Comment: @ZiaYamin  I think we got a lead here. I can serve properly with `php -S  127.0.0.1:9000 -t public/`. But when stopping this and running `php artisan serve` again, the same error as in the question appears.

Comment: Run composer update

Comment: @elyptikus update your composer

Comment: @HedayatullahSarwary Unfortunately no success. Could it have something to do with cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself. I had some wrong variable in my `.env` file which messed up my php path. I deleted it and now everything runs fine:

```
PHP_BINARY="/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php"
```

I used this to debug the site on my shared hosting server. Thanks everyone in the discussions for the good hints.

Comment: Happy that you find it, best of luck.