# Laravel App running on xampp but not with artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

I am trying to run my app via `php artisan serve` on **PHPStorm** IDE but it throws some error that I am unable to understand, When running it via xampp on apache it works like a charm but as soon as I initiate it with `php artisan serve` it halts then an there. Here's the error I get:

```
Warning: require_once(H:\University Documents\UMT\F2021\FYP 2\Smart School System\smartschoolsystem/public/index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\University Documents\UMT\F2021\FYP 2\Smart School System\smartschoolsystem\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'H:\University Documents\UMT\F2021\FYP 2\Smart School System\smartschoolsystem/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\University Documents\UMT\F2021\FYP 2\Smart School System\smartschoolsystem\server.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in H:\University Documents\UMT\F2021\FYP 2\Smart School System\smartschoolsystem\server.php on line 21
```

here's my Server.php:

```
<?php

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Builder::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I tried changing root at `register()` in AppServiceProvider but it ended up sending me to unreachable request, I also changed `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';` to `require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';` in `server.php` it didn't work either. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Apply this StackOverflow question solutions: [Php Artisan serve command not serving Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290052/php-artisan-serve-command-not-serving-laravel-5-8)

Comment: Nope, this ended up generating another error ```The requested resource / was not found on this server.```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php Artisan serve command not serving Laravel 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290052/php-artisan-serve-command-not-serving-laravel-5-8)

Comment: @KaushikThakkar , Faizan already suggested this.