# 'php artisan serve' won't work. tried multiple solutions

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I issued 'composer create-project laravel/laravel first-projec'

after creating a new laravel project I cd'd into the project directory and ran 'php artisan serve'

the console prompted the following error:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\first-projec\public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-projec\public\index.php on line 34

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\first-projec\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-projec\public\index.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-projec\public\index.php on line 34
```

I've tried a couple of solutions with no resolution:

- [run composer install](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Vendor-autoload-is-not-found-Please-run-composer-install-under/td-p/82767): this results in a further problem 'composer.lock doesn't exist'
- [php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331631/why-command-php-artisan-serve-not-working): it says 'Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started' but generates the same error once make a GET request

it has to do with the /vendor/autoload.php file and I couldn't figure it out

Comment: How does that autoload.php file look like? Does it even exist?

Comment: that's the problem, it doesn't exist

Comment: And nothing else in the vendor folder exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially downloaded PHP manually through the official website (php.net), extracted the folder, added it to the Program Files directory, and created the required environmental variables.

I Also installed Composer through the Composer Installer.

the steps above might have caused some obscure problem that I'm not aware of.

## how I solved the problem:

- deleted the PHP folder.
- uninstalled composer.
- downloaded xampp: so PHP would be installed properly unlike the way I did it.
- removed the old env variable and added a new one with the new location.
- installed composer.

now everything is working properly.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove vendor folder, and if composer.lock
exists try to remove that too.

Then run :

```
composer install
```

again.

Also dont firget to use this command the first time you get an error:

```
composer dump-autoload
```