# Running Laravel application is not automatically opening in your browser

Tags: laravel

Laravel application is not automatically opening in my browser `php artisan serve` must open in browser directly

when i execute `php artisan serve` the url must open in browser .

When in start Laravel application it must open in browser directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why command "php artisan serve" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331631/why-command-php-artisan-serve-not-working)

Comment: Why do you need it? Can't you type it manually?

Comment: Write a script that spares you that one click?

Comment: @MitKathrotia  need to do it, manually is possible but ..

Comment: @ditrorio you can create virtual host for it.

Comment: @MitKathrotia how to achive

Comment: @darshita_baldha  virtual host?

Comment: Laravel not support automatically open browser.

Comment: Did you try to search before posting at all?

Comment: Is this on windows(xampp/wamp), wsl, linux or mac?

Comment: @ditrorio yes, explore what is virtual host and then if you are using ubuntu refer this to create it [virtual host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Virtual Hosts are not related to `php artisan serve` and having virtual hosts also won't open your browser

Comment: sorry @darshita_baldha you took me wrong; if i create  virtual host; how it will directly open in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Linux**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the Laravel development server in the background
php artisan serve &

# Wait for a few seconds to make sure the server has started 
sleep 5

# Open the default web browser with the Laravel server URL
xdg-open http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Save the above code in a file as .sh, for example, start_laravel.sh.
`chmod +x start_laravel.sh`
then
`./start_laravel.sh`

**For Windows**

Save the above code in a file as .bat, for example, start_laravel.bat and run

```
@echo off

REM Start the Laravel development server in the background
start "" php artisan serve

REM Wait for a few seconds to make sure the server has started
timeout /t 5

REM Open the default web browser with the Laravel server URL
start http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: Same here, if port 8000 is already taken `php artisan serve` will use port 8001. That code would start the wrong project

Answer (score 0):

I don't think running `php artisan serve` on its own automatically opens your Laravel application in a browser tab. Doing it manually should not be difficult.

But if you really insist, here's a one-liner command for Windows:

```bash
start http://localhost:8000 && php artisan serve --port 8000
```

On Linux:

```bash
xdg-open http://localhost:8000 && php artisan serve --port 8000
```

Comment: what if the port starts on 8001 instead of 8000?

Comment: @MitKathrotia then the command should be `start http://localhost:8001 && php artisan serve --port 8001`

Comment: I asked because according to your answer if the 8000 port is busy then it will start on 8001 and the link will open on port 8000.

Comment: @MitKathrotia Got it. I updated my answer so that either the application is served at the specified port, or it errors upfront.

Comment: So if port 8000 is already taken your script will "fail" and no additional server will be started? What if I want to run two Laravel projects using this script?

Comment: @brombeer Just replace `8000` with an unused port. I assume this much is obvious, so I'll leave it here in the comments.